# Splash screen in Joomla! 2.5 (multilanguage)

Tags: joomla2.5

I set up a multilanguage website, in Joomla! 2.5, without installing any new module in the following way:

- Installed the lanaguage packs
- Set up my different languages in in Extension->language manager
- I created an article, a category and a menu for each language.
- I associated each article to the corresponding category and menu
- Each article is thus the home of its language

Everything work flowlessly, and I can switch from one language to another too (with the language switcher).

I want to put a splash screen *for all languages*.

For this purpose, I created an article with langage="ALL", a category with language="ALL" and set up the article as default of the "Home" menu (langage="ALL")

But when I go to http://example.org/, I get redirected to http://example.org/it/ (which is the *last* language I used), and this last homepage is ignored.

So, how can I prevent Joomla!2.5 to automatically redirect me to my language home? And how can I set Joomla!2.5 to show me the same splash screen for each lanaguages?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could try if you haven't already. From the plugin manager open the System - Language Filter and set the Cookeie Lifetime to Session. Leave the site, clear your browser cache and cross your fingers.

Good luck